# Netlogo: Moving turtles and calculate distance

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently do my project about path planning.

So the step of my plans are like this:

1. Click "setup" to arrange all the coordinate
2. Click "start" to create the moving turtles
3. Click "go" to make the moving turtle going to nearest coordinate (label with "x")
4. Which mean, at step 4, the moving turtle already calculate it's distance with every coordinate.

Here I attach the interface and the coding

[image: The interface]

```
to setup
 clear-all
 set-default-shape turtles "x"
 create-turtles 9
 ask turtles[set color red]

 ask turtle 0[setxy 0 15]
 ask turtle 1[setxy 4 15]
 ask turtle 2[setxy -4 15]
 ask turtle 3[setxy 0 12]
 ask turtle 4[setxy 4 12]
 ask turtle 5[setxy -4 12]
 ask turtle 6[setxy 0 9]
 ask turtle 7[setxy 4 9]
 ask turtle 8[setxy -4 9]
end

to start
 set-default-shape turtles "airplane"
 create-turtles 1

 ask turtle 9[setxy 0 -15]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that distance depends on your topology.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let targets [
    [0 15] [4 15] [-4 15]
    [0 12] [4 12] [-4 12]
    [0 9] [4 9] [-4 9]
  ]
  foreach targets [xy -> ask patch item 0 xy item 1 xy [
    sprout 1 [set shape "x" set color red]
    ]
  ]
  create-turtles 1 [ set shape "airplane" setxy 0 -15]
end
```

**EDIT:** If you treat all other turtles as eligible targets, then once you move `turtle 9` to a target it will stay there.  If you do not want that, you say that a turtle in the same location is not eligible:

```
to move
  ask turtle 9 [move-to min-one-of eligibles [distance myself]]
end

to-report eligibles
  report turtles with [0 < distance myself]
end
```

Comment: thank you Alan.

but when i use your given coding, the system said " Nothinf named XY has been defined"

Comment: @AzamAsri- What version of Netlogo do you have? Alan's code (copied into a brand new file) works for me in Netlogo 6.0.2, but if you have 6.0 you may have to change ... `[xy ->` ... to ... `[ [xy] ->` ...

Comment: Oh, I see. I have version 5.0.4.

I'll try update it first

Comment: Ok. I just updated it and it's working. However, the turtle just move to one location only after that it stop.

i think because it find the nearest turtle is below him. How to solve it?

Comment: @AzamAsri Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).